# Interfacing a Bluetooth 2.0 device with iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, sdk, bluetooth

I would like to ask you just some initial directions on how to send/receive (essentially receive) some data to/from a **bluetooth 2.0 device**. I'm trying CoreBluetooth Framework api with no success.

At the same time, I'm sure the connection can be done due to the fact the the device is already paired within iphone 5s and it works correctly (when an incoming call arrived, by pressing the button on the device the call is opened on the iphone).

Then in particular I need to programmatically intercept (on my app) the button pressing on the device. Could you send me some helps on that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you not have an iOS client and an iOS server you wont have an successfull way to communicate

Comment: CoreBluetooth is only for Bluetooth Low-Energy, not "classical bluetooth" as you suggested in "Bluetooth 2.0 device". ExternalAccessory (with MFI compliance) should be what you want.